# sed remove word + space from a .csv | unix | solaris

Tags: mysql, bash, oracle, unix, sed

I have the below csv file which I want to load to Oracle table.

cat to_load_pplp.csv

```
Table PPL_CH_USAGE,178,01/Sep/2017 09:03:30,01/Sep/2017 09:03:30
PPL_INVOICE,22015731,01/Sep/2017 05:30:21,01/Sep/2017 05:30:21
PPL_LIABILITY,2468705,01/Sep/2017 06:56:41,01/Sep/2017 06:56:41
Table MBBSCS_PPL_INVOICE,3768639,01/Sep/2017 07:00:15,01/Sep/2017 07:00:15
Table MBBSCS_PPL_USAGE,1914718,01/Sep/2017 20:02:03,01/Sep/2017 20:02:03
CONTRACT_MSISDN,3785568,01/Sep/2017 04:00:26,01/Sep/2017 04:00:26
Table OCS_OFFER_CONF_2,16838060,01/Sep/2017 09:30:03,01/Sep/2017 09:30:03
Table OCS_OFFER_STATE_2,12902213,01/Sep/2017 09:30:03,01/Sep/2017 09:30:03
Table OCS_STATIC_2,5094735,01/Sep/2017 09:30:03,01/Sep/2017 09:30:03
Table FC_SAPIST_ALL_ITEMS,4579021,01/Sep/2017 02:40:54,01/Sep/2017 02:40:54
Table FC_SAPIST_OPEN_ITEMS,653676,01/Sep/2017 00:30:05,01/Sep/2017 00:30:05
Table FC_SAPIST_DY_ALL,993408,01/Sep/2017 12:46:46,01/Sep/2017 12:46:46
Table SC_LOAN_OVERVIEW_FACT_II,1392218,01/Sep/2017 08:10:31,01/Sep/2017 08:10:31
PPL_USAGE,21397132,01/Sep/2017 06:19:27,01/Sep/2017 06:19:27
PPL_USAGE,20339944,01/Sep/2017 10:20:16,01/Sep/2017 10:20:16
Table PPL_CH_USAGE,178,01/Sep/2017 09:03:30,01/Sep/2017 09:03:30
```

In order to load them to oracle table , how can I delete the word "Table" and the spacea after it?

For example, desired output will be:

```
PPL_CH_USAGE,178,01/Sep/2017 09:03:30,01/Sep/2017 09:03:30
PPL_INVOICE,22015731,01/Sep/2017 05:30:21,01/Sep/2017 05:30:21
PPL_LIABILITY,2468705,01/Sep/2017 06:56:41,01/Sep/2017 06:56:41
MBBSCS_PPL_INVOICE,3768639,01/Sep/2017 07:00:15,01/Sep/2017 07:00:15
MBBSCS_PPL_USAGE,1914718,01/Sep/2017 20:02:03,01/Sep/2017 20:02:03
CONTRACT_MSISDN,3785568,01/Sep/2017 04:00:26,01/Sep/2017 04:00:26
OCS_OFFER_CONF_2,16838060,01/Sep/2017 09:30:03,01/Sep/2017 09:30:03
OCS_OFFER_STATE_2,12902213,01/Sep/2017 09:30:03,01/Sep/2017 09:30:03
FC_SAPIST_DY_ALL,993408,01/Sep/2017 12:46:46,01/Sep/2017 12:46:46
OCS_STATIC_2,5094735,01/Sep/2017 09:30:03,01/Sep/2017 09:30:03
FC_SAPIST_ALL_ITEMS,4579021,01/Sep/2017 02:40:54,01/Sep/2017 02:40:54
FC_SAPIST_OPEN_ITEMS,653676,01/Sep/2017 00:30:05,01/Sep/2017 00:30:05
SC_LOAN_OVERVIEW_FACT_II,1392218,01/Sep/2017 08:10:31,01/Sep/2017 08:10:31
PPL_USAGE,21397132,01/Sep/2017 06:19:27,01/Sep/2017 06:19:27
PPL_USAGE,20339944,01/Sep/2017 10:20:16,01/Sep/2017 10:20:16
PPL_CH_USAGE,178,01/Sep/2017 09:03:30,01/Sep/2017 09:03:30
```

Please assist me :)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/^Table //g' -i to_load_pplp.csv
```

The s stands for substitute, the `-i` option replaces the file.

Answer (score 3):

By using a substitution command:

```
sed 's/^Table //' file
```

Comment: What is a field contains Table? Some of the lines start with the first field of the csv.

Comment: @123 What do you mean? This removes `Table` and following space at the beginning of the line. That's what OP asks for... no?

Comment: Correct, remove just word "Table" -- Thank you :)